# Entering keypad keys from screen (Virtual keyboard) in Selenium - Java

Tags: java, selenium

I need to enter keypad keys from the screen (touchscreen) and not using keyboard (I can't use send keys). 
Is there any way of doing this?
I am attaching the screenshot of the screen.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess we need the HTML of those buttons

Comment: If you can get the locators for the different buttons, you should be able to click the corresponding button to enter the numbers.

Comment: Selenium is a library that interacts **only** with a browser DOM. Computer peripherals, including touchscreen keyboards, are not a browser. You will need to use some other library that can interact with that peripheral.